# Remotely push DNS server to client via OpenVPN

Tags: networking, dns, openvpn, tcp

When I try to push a DNS server via the OpenVPN server-config I don't get that server to be the first DNS server on the connected client system. It ends up being specified as an alternative DNS server.

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 89.238.75.146" # DNS-Server 1 (local djbdns)
```

To overcome certain network restrictions, if they're at place, I use 443 TCP. - That means that my DNS queries are sent via TCP (if I manually reconfigure the DNS server), which doesn't scale very well from a performance perspective.

Are there any kewl solutions for that?

Marius

Comment: Bit unclear... are you saying you run DNS on port 443 (https)? Anyway, what OS are your clients running?

Comment: - the OpenVPN daemon on the remote server works on 443. The DNSd runs on a Linux box. If I route the traffic through the OpenVPN tunnel the DNS traffic is tunneld through 443, too.

Comment: Gotcha, so the main problem you are trying to overcome is pushed DNS settings don't show up as primary, but as secondary?

Comment: That, and even if I configure it - TCP and DNS don't scale together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've noticed that it differs based on "client". If I use network manager I get the DNS but if I use "regular" openvpn service (in Ubuntu) I don't get the DNS. I haven't look deeper into this since I usually let network manager connect my vpn.

Comment: sorry for accepting this answer rather late... I think something is wrong here with my account connection on StackOF and so on...

Comment: I wanted to vote up Jimmy's answer, but since I can't, I'd like to give thumbs up in this post: Effectively, the NetworkManager openvpn plugin DOES update the /etc/resolv.conf with the DNS options pushed by openvpn server.

Comment: Agree, NetworkManager manages to get that right *sigh* here's hoping for clean `.ovpn` compatibility someday...

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/a/590722/82338

Answer (score 0):

If one is committed to the `openvpn` terminal vector, put a bash script called `~/bin/m0vpn` (for a VPN called `m0`) so I connect by simply opening a terminal and typing:

```
m0vpn
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
OVPNFILE="$HOME/.config/vpn/m0/client.ovpn"
TEMPRESOLV="nameserver 10.0.0.2\ndomain prd1.m0\n"
# The next two lines create a temporary /etc/resolv.conf which includes the original.
# For extra security you may modify this behavior (to use Only your own DNS server)
# ^ But then, you must connect to an IP address (no hostname) from your .ovpn file!
sudo printf "$TEMPRESOLV" | cat - /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf > /tmp/resolv.conf
sudo mv /tmp/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
printf "Temporary /etc/resolv.conf:\n$TEMPRESOLV"
sudo openvpn $OVPNFILE
sudo ln -sf /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
echo "Reset resolv.conf"
```

And perhaps someday `NetworkManager` will simply be able to use the `.ovpn` file.