# How can I get an OpenVPN connection to correctly proxy DNS?

Tags: dns, openvpn, networkmanager

I have a vpn connection I use to connect to work.  It works almost perfectly, here is how I connect:

```
 sudo openvpn --config frew@foo.bar.com.ovpn
```

Unfortunately the DNS doesn't seem to work, so after connecting I have to use the IP Address of the servers I want to connect to.  Interestingly, when I connect with NetworkManager, DNS *does* work, but if there are any connection errors it just drops instead of reconnecting.  Honestly I'd be fine with a fix to either, and will change the title of the question to match the first working answer I get.

I am using the most recent Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Related: [Remotely push DNS server to client via OpenVPN](http://superuser.com/q/64640/664)

Answer (score 3):

I needed to add

```
 up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
 down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

to my ovpn config.